# Pluplod 2.1.2 uploading files and saving to mysql

Tags: mysql, plupload

I have a code of a previous version of plupload that works fine. It does upload the files and saves it to mysql database.

I am trying to upgrade it to the last version of pluplod 2.1.2. I can upload files but it's not saving the data to mysql.

Here's my code. Please any help will be very wellcome. I had a look into all the pupload forums and i don't see the answer on this new version.

Thank you very much.

```
enter code here
<?php
/**
 * upload.php
 *
 * Copyright 2013, Moxiecode Systems AB
 * Released under GPL License.
 *
 * License: http://www.plupload.com/license
 * Contributing: http://www.plupload.com/contributing
 */

#!! IMPORTANT: 
#!! this file is just an example, it doesn't incorporate any security checks and 
#!! is not recommended to be used in production environment as it is. Be sure to 
#!! revise it and customize to your needs.


// Make sure file is not cached (as it happens for example on iOS devices)
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");


$id= $_SESSION['$ide'];
include "mysqlconnection.php";

$ide = $_GET['i'];

session_start();


/* 
// Support CORS
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
// other CORS headers if any...
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    exit; // finish preflight CORS requests here
}
*/

// 5 minutes execution time
@set_time_limit(5 * 60);

// Uncomment this one to fake upload time
// usleep(5000);

// Settings
//$targetDir = ini_get("upload_tmp_dir") . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "plupload";
//$targetDir = 'uploads';
$targetDir = '../images';

$cleanupTargetDir = true; // Remove old files
$maxFileAge = 5 * 3600; // Temp file age in seconds


// Create target dir
if (!file_exists($targetDir)) {
    @mkdir($targetDir);
}

// Get a file name
if (isset($_REQUEST["name"])) {
    $fileName = $_REQUEST["name"];
} elseif (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
} else {
    $fileName = uniqid("file_");
}

$filePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;





$path1= $filename;
//$ref= '98-prueba1';
//$id='98';

//echo '$filePath='.$filePath.'<br/>';
//echo '$filename='.$filename.'<br/>';
//echo '$path1='.$path1.'<br/>';
//echo '$ide='.$ide.'<br/>';    



// Chunking might be enabled
$chunk = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunk"]) : 0;
$chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunks"]) : 0;


// Remove old temp files    
if ($cleanupTargetDir) {
    if (!is_dir($targetDir) || !$dir = opendir($targetDir)) {
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 100, "message": "Failed to open temp directory."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }

    while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
        $tmpfilePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;

        // If temp file is current file proceed to the next
        if ($tmpfilePath == "{$filePath}.part") {
            continue;
        }

        // Remove temp file if it is older than the max age and is not the current file
        if (preg_match('/\.part$/', $file) && (filemtime($tmpfilePath) < time() - $maxFileAge)) {
            @unlink($tmpfilePath);
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
}   


// Open temp file
if (!$out = @fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunks ? "ab" : "wb")) {
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
}

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])) {
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 103, "message": "Failed to move uploaded file."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }

    // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
    if (!$in = @fopen($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "rb")) {
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }
} else {    
    if (!$in = @fopen("php://input", "rb")) {
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }
}

while ($buff = fread($in, 4096)) {
    fwrite($out, $buff);
}

@fclose($out);
@fclose($in);

// Check if file has been uploaded
if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {
    // Strip the temp .part suffix off 
    rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);




//This part is what I added:
if($fileName!=$_SESSION['unique_name']){
    $time=date(DATE_ATOM);
    $con = mysql_connect("mylocalhost","user","pass");
    if (!$con){ die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
    mysql_select_db("bbdd", $con);
   // mysql_query("UPDATE table SET picture1='picture4 Jeh' WHERE id='$id'");

    //$prefijo1 = substr(md5(uniqid(rand())),0,4);
    //$path1 = 'imagenes/viviendas/'. $prefijo1.'_'.$fileName;
    $path1 = 'images/'.$fileName;




$sacaid=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$ide' ");
if ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sacaid)) {
$id = $row["id"];
$refe = $row["refe"];
//$ref = $row["referencia"];
$picture1 = $row['picture1'];
$picture2 = $row['picture2'];
$picture3 = $row['picture3'];
$picture4 = $row['picture4'];
$picture5 = $row['picture5'];
$picture6 = $row['picture6'];
$picture7 = $row['picture7'];
$picture8 = $row['picture8'];
$picture9 = $row['picture9'];
$picture10 = $row['picture10'];
$picture11 = $row['picture11'];
$picture12 = $row['picture12'];
$picture13 = $row['picture13'];
$picture14 = $row['picture14'];
$picture15 = $row['picture15'];
$picture16 = $row['picture16'];
}

if (strlen($picture1) < 25) { 
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET picture1='$path1' WHERE id='$ide' ");  //esto si que lo hace
}
else { //else1
if (strlen($picture2) < 25) { 
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET picture2='$path1' WHERE id='$ide' ");
}
else { //else2
if (strlen($picture3) < 25) { 
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET picture3='$path1' WHERE id='$ide' ");
}
else { //else3
if (strlen($picture4) < 25) { 
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET picture4='$path1' WHERE id='$ide' ");
}
else { //else4
if (strlen($picture5) < 25) { 
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET picture5='$path1' WHERE id='$ide' ");
}
else { //else5
if (strlen($picture6) < 25) { 
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET picture6='$path1' WHERE id='$ide' ");
}
 else { //else6
if (strlen($picture7) < 25) { 
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET picture7='$path1' WHERE id='$ide' ");
}
else { //else7
if (strlen($picture8) < 25) { 
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET picture8='$path1' WHERE id='$ide' ");
}
else { //else8
if (strlen($picture9) < 25) { 
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET picture9='$path1' WHERE id='$ide' ");
}
else { //else9
if (strlen($picture10) < 25) { 
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET picture10='$path1' WHERE id='$ide' ");
}
else { //else10
if (strlen($picture11) < 25) { 
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET picture11='$path1' WHERE id='$ide' ");
}
else { //else11
if (strlen($picture12) < 25) { 
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET picture12='$path1' WHERE id='$ide' ");
}
else { //else12
if (strlen($picture13) < 25) { 
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET picture13='$path1' WHERE id='$ide' ");
}
else { //else13
if (strlen($picture14) < 25) { 
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET picture14='$path1' WHERE id='$ide' ");
}
else { //else14
if (strlen($picture15) < 25) { 
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET picture15='$path1' WHERE id='$ide' ");
}
else { //else15
if (strlen($picture16) < 25) { 
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET picture16='$path1' WHERE id='$ide' ");
} 

} // fin else 1
} // fin else 2
} // fin else 3
} // fin else 4
} // fin else 5
} // fin else 6
} // fin else 7
} // fin else 8
} // fin else 9
} // fin else 10
} // fin else 11
} // fin else 12
} // fin else 13
} // fin else 14
} // fin else 15    

echo '$path1='.$path1.'<br/>';
echo '$ide='.$ide.'<br/>';  



    mysql_close($con);
    $_SESSION['unique_name']=$fileName;
      };
//End what I added




} // ENDING Check if file has been uploaded





// Return Success JSON-RPC response
die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : null, "id" : "id"}');

?>
```

Comment: Do you see the files uploaded on your server? Is the php part you added functional? Check the requests to your server, for example is parameter "i" included in the post parameters? Maybe post your PLupload init code.